# How to unmerge cell with drop-down list and get cells with drop-down list?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to unmerge a cell with drop-down list and then get cells with drop-down list.

Desired behaviour:

C1, C2 and C3 cells should have a drop-down list.

[image]

I tried this but this only keeps the drop-down list in the first cell

```
For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    If cell.MergeCells Then
        Set joinedCells = cell.MergeArea
        cell.MergeCells = False
        joinedCells.Value = cell.Value
    End If
Next
```

Comment: `cell.copy` and `joinedCells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation`

Comment: It's working, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer `Range.Fill` over `Range.Copy` and `Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation` but Scott Craner's suggestion also works.

```
Sub Temp()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim JoinedCells As Range
    For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If Cell.MergeCells Then
            Set JoinedCells = Cell.MergeArea
            Cell.MergeCells = False
            JoinedCells.FillDown
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```